# Linq to SQL: Aggregating over ||

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, autocomplete, aggregate

I'm trying to write a Linq query which fetches all users whose first or last name begins with at least one string in a list of strings. This is used for auto-completion of recipients in a messaging system.

This was my first naive attempt:

```
var users = UserRepository.ALL()
foreach (var part in new [] { 'Ha', 'Ho', 'He' })
{
    string part1 = part; // "Copy" since we're coding lazily
    users = users.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(part1) ||
                             x.FirstName.StartsWith(part1));
}
```

This doesn't work though, as the result becomes:

```
users.Where(a || b).Where(c || d).Where(e || f)...
```

...whereas I want:

```
users.Where(a || b || c || d || e || f || ...)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I should use `Union`...

```
IQueryable<User> result = null;
foreach (var part in terms)
{
    string part1 = part;
    var q = users.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(part1) ||
                             x.LastName.StartsWith(part1));
    result = result == null ? q : result.Union(q);
}
```

Using ReSharper this could be turned into a Linq expression:

```
IQueryable<User> result = terms.Select(part1 =>
    users.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(part1) ||
                     x.LastName.StartsWith(part1)))
         .Aggregate<IQueryable<User>, IQueryable<User>>(
                null, (current, q) => current == null ? q : current.Union(q));
```

...but I'm probably going to go for the `foreach` loop this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use 2 collections - in your code you are filtering down a list ... really you need the collection of filtered lists - not a collection of a list that has been filtered multiple times.

one as a repository for matches and the other witin your loop

```
var userCollection = new Collection<string>();
var users = UserRepository.ALL() 
foreach (var part in new [] { 'Ha', 'Ho', 'He' }) 
{ 
    string part1 = part; // "Copy" since we're coding lazily 
    var matches = users.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(part1) || 
                             x.FirstName.StartsWith(part1)); 
    foreach (var i in matches)
    {
        userCollection.Add(i);
    }
}
```

I am not claiming this is the most elegant solution - just simply trying to point at why your logic is failing.

you can probably do something with Contains

```
var results= from i in collection 
            where idList.Contains(i.Id) 
            select i;
```

just cant see how off the top of my head

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in database performance when it comes to cases like this, but I'd really prefer it if I didn't have to do N queries for N strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner (formatted for readability) that I believe returns the result you seek:

```
 var users = UserRepository.ALL()
    .ToList() //ToList called only to materialize the list
    .Where(x => new[] { 'Ha', 'Ho', 'He' }
        .Any(y => x.LastName.StartsWith(y))
    );  //Don't need it here anymore!
```

It is probably not the efficient solution you were seeking, but I hope it helps you in some way!

EDIT:  As gaearon pointed out, if the 'ALL()' command returns a lot of records, my first solution is probably really bad.  Try this:

```
var users = UserRepository.ALL()
        .Where(x => new[] { 'Ha', 'Ho', 'He' }
            .Any(y => SqlMethods.Like(x.LastName, y + "%"))
        );
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `Any(...)` instead of `Count(...) > 0`.

Comment: Yes, I agree!  I will change it now.

Comment: I think it's still better to write `Any(...)` than `Where(...).Any()` :-)

Comment: This too gives me the old "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Comment: In order to use a function like 'StartsWith', you need to materialize the results.  My favorite way to do this is by calling 'ToList'.  I will update the code with the list being materialized.

Comment: **It's a very bad idea to load all users from database instead of doing a simple query.** This is a very inefficient solution. `StartsWith` is perfectly translated to SQL `LIKE` statement by LINQ to SQL, you just need to make sure you don't mix in-memory and database sources in one query, which we both have done. I think I fixed my code though.

Comment: I agree, that is why I said it is not an efficient solution.  Conceptually 'StartsWith' translates to SQL, but in reality you need something like 'SqlMethods.Like'.  I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code does it for strings.

```
var users = new [] {"John", "Richard", "Jack", "Roy", "Robert", "Susan" };
var prefixes = new [] { "J", "Ro" };

var filtered = prefixes.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(),
    (acc, pref) => acc.Union(users.Where(u => u.StartsWith(pref)).ToList()));
```

For your `User` class it would look like

```
var filtered = prefixes.Aggregate(
    Enumerable.Empty<User>(),
    (acc, pref) => acc.Union(
        users.Where(
            u => u.FistName.StartsWith(pref) || u.LastName.StartsWith(pref)
            ).ToList()));
```

Comment: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Comment: Please consider the edited version, I'm not sure if it solves the problem but it might.

Answer (score -3):

You can construct an expression tree:

```
var parts = new[] { "Ha", "Ho", "He" };

var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "x");

var body = 
    parts.Aggregate<string, Expression>(
        Expression.Constant(false), 
        (e, p) => 
            Expression.Or(e,
                Expression.Or(
                    Expression.Call(
                        Expression.Property(x, "LastName"), 
                        "StartsWith", 
                        null,
                        Expression.Constant(p)),
                    Expression.Call(
                        Expression.Property(x, "FirstName"), 
                        "StartsWith", 
                        null, 
                        Expression.Constant(p)))));

var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(body, x);

var result = users.Where(predicate);
```

The result is the same as:

```
var result =
    users.Where(x => 
        false ||
        x.LastName.StartsWith("Ha") || x.FirstName.StartsWith("Ha") ||
        x.LastName.StartsWith("Ho") || x.FirstName.StartsWith("Ho") ||
        x.LastName.StartsWith("He") || x.FirstName.StartsWith("He") );
```

Comment: Cool but you really **should** use `Contains` instead of constructing expressions. Imagine someone really used this code for autocomplection.

Comment: @gaearon. Imagine that! It would be clearly the end of the world.